Is there a way to do this with a list comprehension?
I have a list that looks something like this:
data = ['1', '12', '123']

I want to produce a new list, that looks like this:
result = ['$1', '1', '$2', '12', '$3', '123']

where the number after the $ sign is the length of the next element.
The straightforward way to do this is with a for loop:
result = []
for element in data:
    result += [f'${len(element)}'] + [element]

but I was wondering if it's possible to do it in a more elegant way - with a list comprehension, perhaps?
I could do
result = [[f'${len(e)}', e] for e in data]

but this results in a list of lists:
[['$1', '1'], ['$2', '12'], ['$3', '123']]

I could flatten that with something like
result = sum([[f'${len(e)}', e] for e in data], [])

or even
result = [x for xs in [[f'${len(e)}', e] for e in data] for x in xs]

but this is getting rather difficult to read. Is there a better way to do this?

I am wonder, what’s the fastest solution of the answers.

You can do it with two loops:
result = [item for s in data for item in (f"${len(s)}", s)]

['$1', '1', '$2', '12', '$3', '123']


Beat me by 6 minutes.

@e-motta, Nice & I upvoted. Kindly see my solution with single loop as well.

There is no need to use list comprehension if it obviously worsens readability.
Just use the way you mentioned:
for element in data:
    result += [f'${len(element)}', element]

The list comprehension is simply not intended to be used for such tasks.

One of the possible solutions is to use chain from itertools:
from itertools import chain


result = list(chain(*[[f'${len(e)}', e] for e in data]))



Great answer but you could avoid the inner list since chain will consume generators: result = list(chain(*([f'${len(e)}', e] for e in data))).

@tdelaney chain doesn't consume your generator. The * does. chain doesn't even know that that happened.

>>> data = ['1', '12', '123']
>>> [x for d in data for x in [f"${len(d)}", d]]
['$1', '1', '$2', '12', '$3', '123']


if what you mean by elegant is one-liner, this is the solution and with single loop
r = [f'${len(data[int(x/2)])}' if x%2==0 else data[int(x/2)] for x in range(2*len(data))]

which is equivalent to
r = []
for x in range(2*len(data)):
    if x % 2 == 0: r.append(f'${len(data[int(x/2)]))
    else: r.append(data[int(x/2)])


Here is another one liner:
data = ['1', '12', '123']
list(sum([(f"${len(x)}",x) for x in data[:]], ()))
# ['$1', '1', '$2', '12', '$3', '123']


A different (and potentially more elegant) approach to achieving this is by using itertools.chain with a generator expression similar to this answer.:
from itertools import chain

data = ['1', '12', '123']
result = list(chain.from_iterable((f'${len(e)}', e) for e in data))

The generator expression ((f'${len(e)}', e) for e in data) is basically generating a tuple for each element in data. This avoids creating an intermediate list of lists or tuples, which is more memory efficient.
